# Make php file function for specific website

Tags: php, javascript, html

Suppose I would have a PHP file on my server. Now in my HTML I have a piece of Javascript code which refers to the path/url of the PHP file. Is it possible to restrict the PHP code to function only for a specifed website?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`

Comment: Check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426825/inspect-the-referrer-in-php

Comment: As others have pointed out, a huge issue is header spoofing. Even the IP address can be spoofed, and while with a spoofed IP address, the attacker might not be able to receive a reply from the server, there are certain cases where they don't even need too. For example, in your case, the code would run on the server, regardless of if a reply was sent back to the original requester.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

---

My assumption is that you have the same PHP script on many different domains, and you want it to behave differently for some domains

---

First off you need to make sure your PHP script has a reliable way of detecting which domain it's running on. This should be in your configuration somewhere. I wouldn't trust `HTTP_REFERER` and `$_SERVER` may not have what you need.

If you have this it should be easy enough to decide what the script should do.

Comment: How do you figure? The javascript is called by the client. How are you  suggesting to differentiate between that call from the specific website (made by the client) and the same call the client would do on their own?

Comment: There is no difference. I'm assuming the JavaScript and PHP run on the same domain. If the PHP script is hailed from may different domains ... there is a problem. You'd need to start working with authentication, like API keys, but that's a can of worms you might not want to open.

Comment: I don't follow. The javascript runs on the client's computer, that's the problem. The client then is always the source of the request, and so you cannot differentiate between the javascript that is present on your domain, and javascript someone put on another domain.

Comment: I think you interpret the question differently. You might be correct, but I think my suggestion still holds. API keys of some sort to identify where you're hailing from (as opposed to a referrer).

Comment: But you can copy that api-key? the request done by javascript (AJAX I presume) is catchable and repeatable by anyone / anywhere still?

Comment: Yep :) But you could have dynamic keys that change over time, but are based on some base key, and are valid for only a short amount of time. But like I said .. a whole 'nother can of worms :P It's the endless quest for usability vs. security.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'site1') {
    // some code...
} else if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'site2') {
    // some other code...
} else {
    // some other code...
}
```