# How can accept connection from specific page?

Tags: php, connection, member-access

I have a web page and I need to accept some of visitors if it is just from a spesific page.

For Example: If visitor goes example.com/member to example.com/specific it will ok.
But if user goes any other place or just from address bar of browser, It will say "connection failed"

How can I do this with php?
Thanks.

Comment: You can check `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but it isn't foolproof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't fool proof though, so don't use it for any authentication or security purpose

```
<?php
if(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])=="http://yourallowedurl.com/etc.html")
{
    echo "OK";
}
else
{
    echo "connection failed";
}
?>
```

[Review This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426825/inspect-the-referrer-in-php)

[And This](http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/feb/referer-buys-you-nothing)

**Note:** You might want to create a session for the people who are logged in and allow only those with proper session values set to visit that protected page.