# Show website content differently depending on how the user came to the site (cookies)?

Tags: javascript, cookies, seo, local-storage, adsense

### The Problem:

I've worked out an agreement with one of my website clients that for every lead that I generate and push to the website, I'll get a % of the sale. So my plan is to setup a custom landing page w/ a "Get Quote" form, a custom phone number (for tracking w/ Google Voice), and starting it off by running a Google Adwords campaign, then analyzing the data through Google Analytics for optimum ROI.

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

*The catch is...*

1. Direct Input (typing into url bar: www.mysite.com)
2. Organic Search Results
3. Backlinks linking to your website

**X - DO NOT COUNT.**

1. Advertising on Google Adwords
2. Advertising on Social Media
3. Advertising w/ Affiliate Softare backlinks

**✓ - DO COUNT.**

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

So... that means I'll need to change out the content of the website depending on how the user arrived. I imagine that their are a few ways to handle this (cookies?, local storage?, javascript trickery?). What's the best way to handle this in 2015?

### My Requirements:

- Depending on how the user arrived, change out the Phone Number with custom Google Voice number for tracking
- Depending on how the user arrived, change out the "Get Quote" form with customized form for tracking
- If the user returns to the website by Direct Input or Organic Search or Backlink after the fact of them clicking through by my advertising, the website content should stay as my customized content.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you only need it for one website: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426825/inspect-the-referrer-in-php ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this the way all affiliate programs work.

Just use an appended parameter, something like http://example.com?aff=rioku in URLs you promote through all channels. Your landing page should check for this parameter and make the desired changes on the page (e.g. phone number etc). You can then also set the cookie with desired information so next time it is counted against you even in the absence of a parameter.